# Dynamic allocation of QImage array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, qt4, qimage

I need to allocate dynamically memory for QImage array.

It worked for me in Linux:

```
void Arrange_Images(int numOfCams, int numBoards)
{
     QImage * array_of_images[numOfCams*numOfBoards];
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

But Windows will not resolve this problem and will mark it as error. 
For a standard array i can use malloc, but this is a QImage array. 
After this each cell will be filled by images for reordering and further processing.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Paste the error message.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. Above is not a `QImage` array, it's an array of *pointers* to `Qimage`. 2. You shouldn't use `malloc` with C++. 3. For raw memory management, you should use `new`, but you really should avoid raw memory management in application code in modern C++. 4. With `QImage`, you don't have to use pointers because it is a lightweight copy-on-write class so you can just use values when possible. 5. Using C-style arrays should also be avoided in modern C++, instead in Qt you could use nested `QList`, or `std::vector`, or `std:array` if you really want fixed-size array.

Comment: And, it worked on Linux probably because you used a compiler, which supports C-style variable length arrays (VLAs) with C++. It is not standard C++, but an extension offered by a specific compiler.

Comment: I can't know the amount of QImages, that i will use, before compiling.
I got a working code in Linux and now i'm trying to transfer it to Windows. I will get it working as is and after that improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Visual Studio compiler still cannot allocate dynamic amount of memory on stack (I think C++03 didn't allowed this, altrough C99 did). You could use [`_malloca`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx) as an analogue. Or just switch to using `gcc` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your dynamic array is not really dynamic.

**array_of_images** is a static array of pointers to QImage objects, and the size of static arrays has to be known at compile time - this size is not known in your case since the size of your array depends on the input parameters of the **Arrange_Images()** function.

If you want to create a dynamically allocated array of QImage objects, you should do this this way:

```
QImage* array_of_images = new QImage[numOfCams*numOfBoards];
```

I would also consider if you really need a dynamically allocated array and cannot replace it with something like std::vector.

If the Linux compiler really allowed it in this form, I'm not sure why as it seems to me that it shouldn't compile.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, after few tries it did work for me this way:
`QImage ** array_of_images;
*array_of_images = new QImage[numOfCams*numOfBoards];`

array_of_images is an array of pointers to QImage cells (each QImage cell is a kind of pointer).

Comment: That is what I was just going to write in the update - you probably wanted an array of pointers to QImage objects, not an array of QImage objects ;)

Answer (score 0):

To get it working quickly, try this line instead of what you have now:

```
std::vector<QImage*> array_of_images(numOfCams*numOfBoards);
```

You will need `#include <vector>` too, of course. Rest of your code should stay identical, as `std::vector` will unallocate itself (but not the stuff the pointers in it point to!) when it goes out of scope, just like your current C-style array does.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it later. It's good idea, i thought as you to use vector or qlist.

Comment: @DmitryKezin Well, using `QList` or `std::vector` is really a matter of preference and style, both are fine in Qt C++ code.